# Prove $\lim_{h\to0}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)$ uniformly if $f\in C_c^{1}(\mathbb R)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I try to use the fact $f\in C_c^1(\mathbb R)$ which means it is a function with compact support whose derivative is continuous. This implies $f'$ is uniform continuous. But then it turns out uniform continuity of the limit function does not imply the uniform convergence of the sequence. Now I am thinking if I can show $f_n$ is equicontinuous, which will then solve the problem. But I cannot manage to show it. I am stuck here. Any hints and comments are appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with $C_c^1(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: It means it is $C^1$ function with compact support. Just edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Since $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R,$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$ implies $|f'(y)-f'(x)|<\epsilon.$ So if $x\in \mathbb R$ and $0<|h|<\delta,$ the MVT shows there exists $c$ between $x$ and $x+h$ such that

$$|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - f'(x)| = |f'(c)-f'(x)|<\epsilon.$$

Comment: Oh yes MVT really works here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Write $f(x+h) - f(x) = \int_x^{x+h} f'(s) d s = h \int_{0}^1 f'(x + t h) d t$ so
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - f'(x) = \int_{0}^1 (f'(x+t h) - f'(x) )\ d t$$

Comment: Then by uniform continuity of $f'$, the right hand side is uniformly small. Thanks!

Comment: @JKDASF: It may be convenient at times to see it as a continuous function of $(x,h)$ that is $0$ for $h=0$. When $f$ is $C^k$ then the function is $C^{k-1}$.