# Uniform convergence of $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ to $f^{\prime}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable and let $f^{\prime}$ be Lipschitz continuous on $[0,1]$. Why is it that
\begin{equation}
  \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f^{\prime}(x)\ \
  \text{uniformly on $[0,1]$}\ ?
\end{equation}

I don't see how the Lipschitz continuity of $f^{\prime}$ helps to conclude the uniform convergence. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: $f'$ is uniformly continuous, so you can apply this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3707346/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x+h)-f(x)=h f'(z_h)$ where $z_h\in[x,x+h]$ (or $[x+h,x]$ if $h<0$). So $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(z_h).$$

Now $|f'(z_h)-f'(x)|\le L |z_h-x|\le L|h|$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{f(x+h ) -f(x)}{h} -f'(x) \right|=|f'(\theta ) -f'(x)|\leq M|\theta -x| \leq M|h|$$
Since $\theta \in [x, x+h]$ by Lagrange theorem.

So $$\lim_{h\to 0} \sup_{x} \left|\frac{f(x+h ) -f(x)}{h} -f'(x) \right| \leq \lim_{h\to 0} M|h| =0$$
which means that the convergence is uniform.

Comment: I've just come across the posting again... What if the Lipschitz continuity is only available on $[0,1]$? I am having trouble to estimate $\lvert f^{\prime}(\theta)-f^{\prime}(x)\rvert$ as the point $\theta\in[x,x+h]$ need not necessarily belong to $[0,1]$, no?